# How to find OEP when the address of entry point is zero in PE header?

Tags: portable-executable, ollydbg

I want to analyze a file in OllyDbg, however, the "address of entry point" in this file is `0x0000`. So it will run the MZ signature as beginning part of the ASM code.

Most debuggers are also unable to debug it directly.
How could I find the original entry point to modify the header?

Comment: this is `DLL` ? because `EXE` can not have no entry point

Comment: I am sure it is an exe file, that's why I need to find the OEP to modify the header.

Comment: Both, an `.EXE` and a `.DLL` file, have entry points,

Comment: exe can not have 0 in  "address of entry point"

Comment: @zx485 - for DLL is valid not have entry point (0 in `AddressOfEntryPoint`) but EXE **must** have not zero `AddressOfEntryPoint`

Comment: may be in your case exe have Tls callbacks ? and in this callback it set exception handler (VEX) for hook execution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `AddressOfEntryPoint` in `EXE` set to 0 - so `EXE` and have no this entry point. In this case, for not crash `EXE` must have the TLS callbacks - look for `IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY` (`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS`) and `AddressOfCallBacks` must be not 0. So this is real entry point(s) of this `EXE` - no other option, otherwise EXE will crashes.

> Most debuggers are also unable to debug it directly.

This happens if debugger set breakpoint on entrypoint. In this case "entrypoint" will be on `MZ` - and when debugger set breakpoint (`0xcc` opcode) here - damage `MZ` signature. As result in process initialization was exception (`user32.UserClientDllInitialize -> ntdll.CsrClientConnectToServer -> RtlImageNtHeaderEx` (error because `MZ` damaged by breakpoint) )

But if debugger has not set a breakpoint on entrypoint - no problem in debugging.

So solution is to look for `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS.AddressOfCallBacks` or set breakpoint to `LdrpCallTlsInitializers`

---

really this was `CLR` (`.NET`) image - in this images type entry point is formal and not used after xp. system ignore it and call [`_CorExeMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh0859k0(v=vs.110).aspx) in `mscoree.dll` as entry point.

But if you try to debug this with the debugger which auto set breakpoint to entrypoint (how debugger thinks) - the `MZ` (`IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`) is damaged. as result `RtlImageNtHeader[Ex]` return 0 (error) for `EXE` and application crashed (under this debugger)

Comment: I searched for TLS Directory. 'TLS directory RVA' and 'TLS directory size' they both are set to zero. In this case again TLS structure is in MZ?

Comment: @bahare - in this case no TLS in exe. are this exe at all executed ?

Comment: Very surprisingly yes! It runs properly. Sounds it runs the MZ as instruction code. Because when I open it in IDA the after two push and pop, inc and dec, there is a jump (located at 0x00400004) to 0x004139EF. So I believe 0x139EF is the RVA of original entry point.

Comment: Perhaps a load-time dependency DLL is modifying the process in memory (in its DllMain) so that by the time the loader is ready to jump to the entry point, a nonzero value is present?  Try stepping through the loader code by using "System breakpoint" in OllyDbg.

Comment: Can you list the first 16 or 32 bytes of the MZ header?

Comment: @bahare - hard say exactly without view this `exe` what happens, if you can share it - will very easy view what exactly happens.  this is not `CLR` exe and it not have own private DLLs ?

Comment: `Sounds it runs the MZ as instruction code` - PE header is read-only and not executable memory. so it must crash on systems with DEP

Comment: @byteptr `00400000                 dec     ebp
00400001                 pop     edx
00400002                 push    edx
00400003                 inc     ebp
00400004                 jmp     loc_4139EF
00400004 __ImageBase     endp
00400009                 align 4
0040000C                 db 0FFh
0040000D                 db 0FFh
0040000E                 db    0
0040000F                 db    0
00400010                 db 0B8h ;`

Comment: @bahare - this "instructions" - only interpret of `MZ` - really never executed. not give any info. if you can share exe - i can easy debug it and exactly say what happens. this is not CLR exe ? it have no private DLLs ?

Comment: @RbMm you are right, it is hard to say without having the actual file to look at, I'm afraid I can not share the sample we are working on. By looking at import table, I don't see any private DLL.

Comment: @bahare it not CLR ?

Comment: @RbMm the packer of the sample was in .NET, however I am not sure about the sample. PEID doesn't show anything concerning the language and IDA applies vcseh signature. How could I check if it is CLR?

Comment: @bahare - `.NET` == `CLR` now understand. really entry point in `.NET` executables not used at all. so all clear here.

Comment: @bahare - real ep in .net (clr) is `_CorExeMain` in mscoree.dll

Answer (score 0):

`0x00000000` is valid value for `Address` of entry point in `PE` file, malware uses this trick to make its debugging hard.

Visual Studio can debug a binary that have `EP == 0`.